# Does aspectratio change the width or the height of a frame?

Tags: beamer

If I use not the `aspectratio` option of the Beamer class, the slides are 128×96 mm.

If I use, e.g., `aspectratio=169`, what do I get? 128×72 mm or 171×96 mm?

Comment: why don't you try? every pdf reader show you the page sizes.

Comment: It depends on the aspect ration you use. Some change both dimensions, others only change the width.

Comment: You can find all the aspect rations with their corresponding page sizes in section `8.3 Frame and Margin Sizes` of the beamer documentation

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Oh my! Re the Beamer docs, I don't know if it's just me, but _I always feel lost in the Beamer manual_. So, thank you very much for the reference!

Comment: @gboffi Beamer has A LOT of options, which makes the manual quite long. Good thing pdf viewers a search option :)

Answer (score 2):

Neither the height nor the width are fixed: both may be adjusted when setting `aspectratio` to give 'convenient' dimensions of about the same scale.

Comment: The height is fixed for rations which are calculated on the fly.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I know :) But the wider point is that when you change the `aspectratio`, 'stuff changes'.

Comment: I imagine that one keeps the height _almost fixed_, and because we love integers for 169 it's 177×99, for 1610 its 160×100 …